# SCAN and CSCAN algorithm

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, disk, disk-io

I am having hard time understanding the working of SCAN and CSCAN algorithm of disk scheduling.I understood FCFS,Closest Cylinder Next but heard that SCAN resembles elevator mechanism and got confused.
My book says that for the incoming order :[10 22 20 2 40 6 38] (while the disk currently at 20) the SCAN moving at the start serves [(20) 20 22 38 40 10 6 2]; this requires moves of [0 2 16 2 30 4 4] cylinders, a total of 58 cylinders.
How does the pattern [(20) 20 22 38 40 10 6 2] came?

Comment: Would u  please clarify CSCAN too  using the same example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's know what the SCAN(Elevator) disk-scheduling algorithm says:-

> It scans down towards the nearest end and then when it hits the bottom
>   it scans up servicing the requests that it didn't get going down. If a
>   request comes in after it has been scanned it will not be serviced
>   until the process comes back down or moves back up.

So, in your case, the current position of disk is at 20. So, as per the SCAN algorithm, it'll scan towards the nearest end, and just after hitting bottom, it scans up servicing the requests back up.

The order is :-

```
|                                                     |


| * current position                                  | * move back up to upside
|---> nearest disk is this one                        |
|     so it'll move down and so on.                   |
|         as it hit the bottom                     _______
```

____

```
                   Fig :- Demonstration of SCAN algorithm
```

So, as per the given data, the order will be `[(20) 20 22 38 40 10 6 2];`

---

**EDIT :-**

The only difference between SCAN and CSCAN is that in CSCAN,

> it begins its scan toward the nearest end and works it way all the way
>   to the end of the system. **Once it hits the bottom or top it jumps to
>   the other end and moves in the same direction**,unlike the SCAN which
>   moves back to upside using the same path.

As per CSCAN,the direction of movement would be same uptil bottom and then it'll reverse the path.

So, as per the given data, the order will be `[(20) 20 22 38 40 2 6 10];` Notice the change in last three disk positions.

I hope it is clear. Feel free to ask remaining doubts.

Comment: Thanku so much ...I can't express gratitude in words

Comment: How is that related to elevator btw?

Comment: SCAN is related to elevator as if the elevator goes in one direction,it retracts the same direction. SAy elevator goes from 1st floor to 3rd floor. So,it'll return back to ground floor using the same path back downside.I hope it is clear. Please upvote the answer...

Comment: what happens if request on same blocks come continuously? for example if the queue is 20 20 20 20 22 38 40 2 6 10 ? Does SCAN algorithm serves all request on block 20 and then move forward?

Comment: @DebobrotoDas - What makes you think it as a special case? It'll behave as expected.